# requirement to display locally downloaded files in a browser

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a web app in asp which downloads pretty huge files to the user's local system. I have a requirement to open a viewer and read this files. Now the thing is this cannot be down using HTML5 because the filesystem APIs work on a sandboxed system and the file APIs can only read when the user has selected a file. I know the path of the downloaded files and I want a seamless experience. So I was hoping if there was any platform independent way I could interact with these files? I would prefer a client site code that could run in the browser but that seems impossible

Comment: It seems impossible because it *is* impossible.

Comment: It is not very clear : what is the link between the asp server app you have and the local file system of the user. What is on the server, what is on the client ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a signed Java Applet.